# CSS Columns 100% height with body margin

Tags: css, height

i have this site: http://manual.businesstool.dk/

And i want the columns to fit the window, with the body margin. It still expands beyond the window because of the margin,
why?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to get rid of the `height: 100%;` declaration and instead add `bottom: 0;`.

Another way is to use `box-sizing: border-box;` but that isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Where should i add the bottom: 0?